# SQL cursor SUM VARCHAR duplicate

Tags: sql-server, sum, cursor, varchar

```
 DECLARE @sscc as INT;
 DECLARE @orders as varchar(255);
 DECLARE @value as varchar(255);
 DECLARE @cOrders as CURSOR;
 SET @value = 'Orders : '

 SET @cOrders = CURSOR FOR
 SELECT SSCC,ORDERS FROM dbo.TIM_StockGeo tsg WITH(NOLOCK)

 OPEN @cOrders

 FETCH NEXT FROM @cOrders INTO @sscc,@orders

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @value = @value + ' ' + @orders;
        PRINT CAST(@SSCC AS VARCHAR(64)) +  ' ' + @value;
        FETCH NEXT FROM @cOrders INTO @sscc,@orders;
    END

CLOSE @cOrders;
DEALLOCATE @cOrders;
```

I have that data :

```
10005555    /18/56789/01/1
10005555    /18/56654/01/1
10005555    /18/52090/01/1
10001111    /18/11111/01/1
10001111    /18/12121/01/1
10002222    /18/89283/01/1
```

I want present this at that way :

```
10005555    /18/56789/01/1, /18/56654/01/1, /18/52090/01/1
10001111    /18/11111/01/1, /18/12121/01/1
10002222    /18/89283/01/1
```

Could anyone help me ? :)

I tried with cursor :

But i don't know how ascribe to variable only duplicate data.

so my output data looks like this.. :

```
10005555 Orders :  /18/56789/01/1
10005555 Orders :  /18/56789/01/1 /18/56654/01/1
10005555 Orders :  /18/56789/01/1 /18/56654/01/1 /18/52090/01/1
10001111 Orders :  /18/56789/01/1 /18/56654/01/1 /18/52090/01/1 /18/11111/01/1
10001111 Orders :  /18/56789/01/1 /18/56654/01/1 /18/52090/01/1 /18/11111/01/1 /18/12121/01/1
10002222 Orders :  /18/56789/01/1 /18/56654/01/1 /18/52090/01/1 /18/11111/01/1 /18/12121/01/1 /18/89283/01/1
```

I use SQL server 2014

Comment: Without code or a database tag, there is nothing that anyone can do to help.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: i'am sorry for that i do not added my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code suggests this is for SQL Server? If that's right and I correctly understand, what you want to achieve, there's no need for a cursor at all.

It can be done with a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT tsg1.sscc,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + tsg2.orders
                     FROM dbo.tim_stockgeo tsg2
                     WHERE tsg2.sscc = tsg1.sscc
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') orders
       FROM dbo.tim_stockgeo tsg1
       GROUP BY tsg1.sscc;
```

Or, if you're already using SQL Server version 2017 or above, even simpler:

```
SELECT tsg1.sscc,
       string_agg(tsg1.orders, ', ') orders
       FROM dbo.tim_stockgeo tsg1
       GROUP BY tsg1.sscc;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f2d72/1)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that! I Use SQL server 2014 so the first query is for me :)